# Trying to use $push in mongoose to add id to another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to be able to add the id for a like into a report.

This is my like route like/add is the route in question:

```
const express = require('express')
const likeRoutes = express.Router()
let Like = require('../models/Like')
let Report = require('../models/Report')


likeRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    Like.find(function(err, like) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.json(like)
        }
    })
})

likeRoutes.route('/:id').get(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    let id = req.params.id
    Like.findById(id, function(err, like){
        res.json(like)
    })
})

likeRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res){
    let like = new Like({
        value: req.body.value,
        _report: req.body._report
    })
    like.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
            console.log(req.body._report)
        Report.findOneAndUpdate(req.body._report,
            { $push: { like: doc._id} },
            { new: true , useFindAndModify: false},
            (err, post) => {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json({doc})
            }
        )
    })

})

likeRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res){
    Like.findById(req.params.id, function(err, like) {
        if (!like)
            res.status(404).send('data is not found')
        else
            like.title = req.body.title
            like.desc = req.body.desc
            like.markdown = req.body.markdown

            like.save().then(like => {
                res.json('Like updated!!!')
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send('Update didnt work')
            })
    })
})

module.exports = likeRoutes
```

This is my report model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let Report = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    summary: {
        type: String
    },
    analysis: {
        type: String
    },
    source_title: {
        type: String
    },
    source_link: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String
    },
    like: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Like'
    },
    player: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Player'
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Report', Report)
```

This is my like model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let Like = new Schema({
    value: {
        type: Number
    },
    _report: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Report'
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Like', Like)
```

When I try to add a like in postman, the like is able to be created.

However, when I go to view the report for the specific like, the like is not present.

I'm guessing that this is an issue with how my model or route is configured.

When I console.log req.body._report, the correct value comes through.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have like set to be an array in my report schema. $push only works if the the schema you push into is an array: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/